# no module named Numpy, but Numpy already exists

Tags: python, numpy, installation, pip

in command prompt i'm trying to run a fuzzy-joiner, but it keeps giving me the error "No module named 'numpy'". I try installing numpy with "pip install numpy" but it's already satisfied as i use it fairly often. Can't figure out why the program can't find numpy. All installations are in python 3.

```
C:\Users\nckea\Documents\Python Programs\fuzzyJoiner-master\fuzzyJoiner-master>pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\nckea\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (1.20.1)

C:\Users\nckea\Documents\Python Programs\fuzzyJoiner-master\fuzzyJoiner-master>python3 preloaded_runner.py --input testdata --entity_type people --loss_function adapted-loss --model model --tokenizer tokenizer --previous_test yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nckea\Documents\Python Programs\fuzzyJoiner-master\fuzzyJoiner-master\preloaded_runner.py", line 2, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

C:\Users\nckea\Documents\Python Programs\fuzzyJoiner-master\fuzzyJoiner-master>
```

Comment: You probably need `pip3` if you're using `python3`. Another way to be sure you have the right `pip` if you have an issue like this is to use `python3 -m pip`.

Comment: There are many questions on SO that you can find by googling "no module named numpy requirement already satisfied", have you checked if any can help you?

Comment: all posts i've seen only solve when numpy is not installed. I havent seen a post where it can't find the module but it's already installed.

Comment: I've used both pip commands